# Cómo evitar falsos negativos al escanear puertos en Golang

Tags: go, hack, nmap, security

muy buenas.

**Contexto:**
Actualmente estoy intentando desarrollar un escáner de puertos usando Golang, que solamente diga si dichos puertos están abiertos o cerrados.

**Problema:**
A pesar de que compila y se ejecuta, muy rara vez muestra de verdad todos los puertos abiertos. Por ejemplo, al escanear los 1000 primeros del dominio *google.com*, no siempre reporta el 80 o el 443. En cambio, al usar una herramienta externa como *nmap* sí que los cataloga como abiertos.

**Código:**

Escáner de un solo puerto:

```golang
func pingTCP(host string, port int, timeout time.Duration, retries int) bool {
    try := 0                                 // current try
    status := false                          // open port flag
    addr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", host, port) // format address
    for try < retries && !status {
        conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", addr, timeout) // connect to given addres with a timeout
        if err == nil {
            conn.Close()  // close the open connection
            status = true // port is open
        } else {
            logger.Put(err.Error())
        }
        try++
    }
    return status
}
```

Escáner de múltiples puertos usando concurrencia:

```golang
func pingTCPRange(host string, ports []int, timeout time.Duration, threads int, retries int) map[int]bool {
    results := map[int]bool{}
    // concurrency: wait group
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(len(ports))
    // concurrency: locks
    mlock := sync.Mutex{}
    tlock := make(chan struct{}, threads)
    // concurrent ping

    for _, port := range ports {
        tlock <- struct{}{} // lock a thread
        // scan a port
        go func(port int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            status := pingTCP(host, port, timeout, retries)
            // concurrency: mutual exclusion
            mlock.Lock()
            // progress
            // logger.Progress("Checking %d", port)
            results[port] = status
            mlock.Unlock()
            <-tlock // unlock a thread
        }(port)
    }
    wg.Wait() // wait for all goroutines to finish

    return results
}
```

Este es el código del programa completo *(es un paquete que forma parte de un programa superior)*:

```golang
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// PACKAGE
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

package scanner

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// IMPORTS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

import (
    "errors"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/jedib0t/go-pretty/table"

    "github.com/cosasdepuma/elliot/pkg/app"
    "github.com/cosasdepuma/elliot/pkg/logger"
    "github.com/cosasdepuma/elliot/pkg/modules"
)

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SUBCOMMAND DEFINITION
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Nmap TODO
var Nmap = modules.Module{
    Flag: args,
    Run:  Run,
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ARGUMENTS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var (
    args    = flag.NewFlagSet("nmap", flag.ContinueOnError)
    host    = args.String("host", "127.0.0.1", "Host a escanear")
    port    = args.String("port", "1-1000", "Puertos a escanear")
    timeout = args.Duration("timeout", 1*time.Second, "Timeout")
    threads = args.Int("threads", 1000, "Number of threads")
    retries = args.Int("retries", 1, "Number of retries if a port is close")
)

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// PUBLIC METHODS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Run TODO
func Run(core *app.Core) {
    // Get the arguments
    flag.Parse()
    // Parse "port" argument
    ports, err := portSplitter(*port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("[!] %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    // Resolve host
    ipaddr, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("", *host)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("[!] Bad host: %s", *host)
        return
    }
    ip := ipaddr.String()
    if *host != ip {
        *host = fmt.Sprintf("%s (%s)", *host, ip)
    }
    // Scan ports
    logger.Command("nmap", "Scanning %d port(s) from %s", len(ports), *host)
    maxThreads := len(ports) * *retries
    if maxThreads < *threads {
        logger.Warning("Optimizing the number of threads from %d to %d", *threads, maxThreads)
        *threads = maxThreads
    }
    result := pingTCPRange(ip, ports, *timeout, *threads, *retries)

    // Filter open ports
    openPorts := make([]int, 0)
    for port, open := range result {
        if open {
            openPorts = append(openPorts, port)
        }
    }

    // ! Beautify ports (just dev)

    t := table.NewWriter()
    t.SetStyle(table.StyleRounded)
    if len(openPorts) == 0 {
        t.AppendHeader(table.Row{"No open ports"})
    } else {
        sort.Ints(openPorts)
        t.AppendHeader(table.Row{"protocol", "port", "status"})
        for _, port := range openPorts {
            t.AppendRow(table.Row{"tcp", port, "open"})
        }
    }
    logger.Put("\n%s", t.Render())
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// PRIVATE METHODS
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// * Utilities

func portSplitter(raw string) ([]int, error) {
    portMap := map[int]struct{}{} // force ports to be unique

    // split ports
    blocks := strings.Split(raw, ",") // split blocks
    for _, block := range blocks {
        rang := strings.SplitN(block, "-", 2) // split ranges
        low, err := strconv.Atoi(rang[0])     // lower port
        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.New("Bad port specification")
        }
        // append ports
        if len(rang) == 1 {
            portMap[low] = struct{}{} // single port
        } else {
            high, err := strconv.Atoi(rang[1]) // higher port
            if err != nil {
                return nil, errors.New("Bad port specification")
            }
            for port := low; port <= high; port++ {
                portMap[port] = struct{}{} // multiple ports
            }
        }
    }
    // retrieve ports
    ports := make([]int, 0, len(portMap))
    for port := range portMap {
        ports = append(ports, port)
    }
    return ports, nil
}

// * Workflow

func pingTCP(host string, port int, timeout time.Duration, retries int) bool {
    try := 0                                 // current try
    status := false                          // open port flag
    addr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", host, port) // format address
    for try < retries && !status {
        conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", addr, timeout) // connect to given addres with a timeout
        if err == nil {
            conn.Close()  // close the open connection
            status = true // port is open
        } else {
            logger.Put(err.Error())
        }
        try++
    }
    return status
}

func pingTCPRange(host string, ports []int, timeout time.Duration, threads int, retries int) map[int]bool {
    results := map[int]bool{}
    // concurrency: wait group
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(len(ports))
    // concurrency: locks
    mlock := sync.Mutex{}
    tlock := make(chan struct{}, threads)
    // concurrent ping

    for _, port := range ports {
        tlock <- struct{}{} // lock a thread
        // scan a port
        go func(port int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            status := pingTCP(host, port, timeout, retries)
            // concurrency: mutual exclusion
            mlock.Lock()
            // progress
            // logger.Progress("Checking %d", port)
            results[port] = status
            mlock.Unlock()
            <-tlock // unlock a thread
        }(port)
    }
    wg.Wait() // wait for all goroutines to finish

    return results
}
```

Muchísimas gracias por todo de antemano

Answer (score 1):

**Lo que probablemente esté pasando es que en esos puertos el protocolo ICMP esta filtrado.**

Esto pasa por medidas anti flooding,
el escanéo por Ping se suele usar para reconocer hosts activos en la red.

Si lo que deseas es hacer un escáner de puertos más "eficiente" (y hacerlo tú) podrías probar con un ACK Scan.

Ampliacion Filtrado ICMP:
https://www.daemon.be/maarten/icmpfilter.html

Técnicas de escaneo de puertos:
https://nmap.org/man/es/man-port-scanning-techniques.html